# drop of water on mousepad of macbook pro and now the mouse is being odd?

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I had wet hair and some drops of water landed on my trackpad. It happened on last friday or thursday, so like 4 or so days ago. And basically now my mouse will just randomly click on stuff and right click too and for the first couple hours I couldn't use it and I wasn't able to get it to work except for the top portion of the mousepad. and now It's no longer that bad, but it still randomly clicks and moves around. should I take it to a genius bar or do you think it'll just eventually stop? any help would be really appreciated and sorry I know this has probably been asked a hundred times.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you may have liquid damage to the system. If this is the case, the issues won't just go away. Water-based liquids are very corrosive to electronics and the damage cannot undo itself. However, you can certainly take it to the Genius Bar. However, I wouldn't mention the water droplets to them. If they can't visibly see the liquid damage and can confirm the issue (and provided you are under warranty), they may replace the trackpad piece free of charge.